# Why is my subdomain redirecting to my main domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So basically, I have a subdomain, `m.mydomain.com.au` although every time I visit it, I am redirected to `www.mydomain.com.au/m`.

For example, if I attempt to go to `m.mydomain.com.au/contact.php`, I am automatically redirected to `www.mydomain.com.au/m/contact.php`

I have never attempted to modify my `.htaccess` file before, but I believe it is causing the problem at the moment.

All help and suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Here is my full `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Use Mod_deflate to compress static files
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
<filesmatch ".(js|css|ico|txt|htm|html|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

# Speed up caching
FileETag MTime Size

# Expires
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 366 days"

# Future Expires Headers
<filesmatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Sat, 27 Dec 2014 23:59:59 GMT"
</filesmatch>


RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com\.au
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.au/$1 [R=permanent,L]

#RewriteBase /


RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that both your subdomain and main domain have the same document root (and thus use the same htaccess file), this is the rule that's causing the redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com\.au
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.au/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This essentially says, if the domain is **not** `www.mydomain.com.au`, redirect it to `http://www.mydomain.com.au/`.

You need to add an additional check so that it doesn't redirect your subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.mydomain\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.au/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Or only redirect the domain without the `www.`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.au/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. Please see the examples again. The redirect is going to `www.mydomain.com.au/m`, not `www.mydomain.com.au`

Comment: @fizzix there's nothing in your htaccess file that is redirecting to the `/m/` folder, so who knows.

Answer (score 1):

It's this rule here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com\.au
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.au/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

The rule basically says that if the `HTTP_HOST` (i.e. the HTTP `Host:` header, which is the domain name used to access the site) is not `www.mydomain.com.au` then it will send a HTTP HTTP 301 ("permanent redirection") to the `www` domain.

Remove these two lines and you'll get what you want - but you'll lose the canonical domain name redirection.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. Please see the examples again. The redirect is going to `www.mydomain.com.au/m`, not `www.mydomain.com.au`

Comment: Sorry mate, didn't seem to fix my problem. Check out the edit I made to my question.