# routing to a rails subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, dns

I have a domain, let's say **example.com** and I want to create a subdomain like **page.example.com**.

I've added a route in my rails routes.rb file:

```
class MySubDomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain == ("page" || "page.example.com")
  end
end

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints(MySubDomain) do
    get '/' => 'static_pages#some_page'
  end

  root to: 'something#else'
```

When I browse to page.example.com in development (using pow) then it lands on the appropriate controller. For production I've created a DNS entry like:

**A record** for **page.example.com** pointing to **IP of the VPS**.

When I hit **page.example.com** in the browser then it just sends me to **example.com**.

When I curl **page.example.com** then the response is the one I expect.

My nginx config is as follows:

```
upstream example.com {server unix:/tmp/benchmark_app.sock fail_timeout=0;}

server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        root /home/deploy/example/public;
        server_name example.com page.example.com;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://unix:/home/deploy/example/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        error_page 404 /404;
        error_page 500 /500;
}
```

**EDIT** : I've changed the routes, added curl response and added nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the webserver is set up to redirect all subdomains to the top level domain?

i.e. a similar issue to this one: [Why is my subdomain redirecting to my main domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862181/why-is-my-subdomain-redirecting-to-my-main-domain)

Comment: I've added my nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

I would test these changes locally by modifying your hostfile (adding "127.0.0.1 test.example.com") and then hit that to check if it's a rails problem or a webserver problem.

GL

Comment: Even easier you can use the lvm.me domain. lvh.me and all subdomains point to 127.0.0.1. No need to endlessly modify your hosts file.

Comment: I use pow. That means I can already visit example.dev and page.example.dev. As mentioned, it works on pow.